# .NET reflection emit - what am I doing wrong in writing this method in MSIL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cil, reflection.emit

I am trying to dynamically create a delegate that returns a list of the values of all properties defined on an object, using reflection emit in C#.

I have started with the examples given here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/exczf7b9(v=vs.100)

Then, I have used LinqPad to view the IL for the code I want to emit.
E.g., for this code:

```
void Main()
{
    new Zap{ Name = "1", Value = 2 }.Test();
}


public class Zap
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<object> Test()
    {
        return new List<object> {Name, Value}; // This is what I want to do...
    }
}
```

I got this IL code for the `Test()` method:

[image: IL code]

But when I run this code, I get a `System.InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'` exception:

```
new Target().DoMagic();

public class Target
{
    delegate List<object> ListProps();
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; } = "zap";
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; } = 77;

    public void DoMagic()
    {
        Type[] methodArgs = { };
        DynamicMethod listPropsMethod = new DynamicMethod("ListProps", typeof(List<object>), methodArgs, typeof(Target).Module);

        ConstructorInfo? constructor = typeof(List<object>).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        MethodInfo? addMethod = typeof(List<object>).GetMethod("Add");

        ILGenerator il = listPropsMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructor);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(MyProperty1), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetGetMethod());
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, addMethod);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0, this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(MyProperty2), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetGetMethod());
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Box);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, addMethod);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var value = listProps();
        Console.WriteLine("Result : " + JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }
}
```

I probably miss a lot of details (e.g., I don't see how calling methods would know which instances to use...), but if someone can shed some light on how I can make this work, I would be grateful.

Also, will invoking the generated delegate created with `emit` be as fast as writing the first code snippet and compiling it? I am troubled by the reflection code I use to get the method/property information, and I wonder if this might cause some performance issues.

Comment: observations: (I'll check more in a minute) - `box` looks weird without a value-type check (box-any might work fine, but you'd need to specify the type); but: what is the target obj of the callvirt? you might need to stloc, ldloc, ldloc to get the target back in the right place (edit: maybe the dup is handling that - I'll build a stack tree in a moment to check)

Comment: your method args are empty; what is `Ldarg_0` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Right! I have updated the `box` instruction now! But the problem remains.

Comment: this: `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0, this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(MyProperty2), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetGetMethod());` is gibberish - nearly have it working, one moment

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, it appears I have messed up this line... I have it fixed too now.

Comment: also: box needs a target type

Comment: as a side note: if you're doing this to learn IL, great! however, as someone who has spent decades fighting IL: *the need for this is decreasing* (heck, I'm actively trying to *remove* IL emit from a bunch of places) - these days, Roslyn code generation should be preferred over IL-emit, for *tons* of reasons

Comment: It partly is for educational purposes, but I was thinking of trying to use it, if I ever get a good grasp of it. There are cases where I would like to avoid using reflection, to avoid the performance penalty. I am not sure how flexible Roslyn code generation is. Can I create methods dynamically, without having to load compiled assemblies? I have now found this link that I am planning to have a look at: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/dynamic-class-creation-roslyn .

Comment: the short answer is "usually"; runtime ref-emit is has advantages and disadvantages; my considered opinion (and I've done a *lot* of ref-emit) is that usually the balance leans in favor of build-time code generation; this often requires different approaches. Ultimately your build-time generator can spit out regular C# - mix that with `partial class` and more recently: `partial` *methods*, and you have some great tricks. The .NET 8 SDK also introduced "interceptors" which are a powerful way to influence normal code. Huge topic, but perhaps smaller than ref-emit!

Comment: Your edits basically took out what the issue was. If you want to delete the question go ahead. But don't remove the issue otherwise people don't understand what was going on, as the asnwer is the same as the question.

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry. I've tried to remove the silly parts, like the console log that logged nothing and some accidental clipboard cuts I had done to the second `.Add()` while posting to this site, which went unnoticed to me. The main issue was the missing `this` parameter, and maybe also the replacement of `OpCodes.Call` which didn't seem to make much difference in this particular case but might be a good idea.

Comment: @Charlieface Also, the missing box type was an issue, probably because I am blind and didn't notice it at all... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this should work:

```cs
delegate List<object> ListProps(Target obj);
```

and:

```cs
Type[] methodArgs = { typeof(Target) };
DynamicMethod listPropsMethod = new DynamicMethod("ListProps", typeof(List<object>), methodArgs, typeof(Target).Module);

ConstructorInfo? constructor = typeof(List<object>).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
MethodInfo? addMethod = typeof(List<object>).GetMethod("Add");

ILGenerator il = listPropsMethod.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructor);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(MyProperty1), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetGetMethod());
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, addMethod);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(MyProperty2), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetGetMethod());
il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(int));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, addMethod);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var listProps = (ListProps)listPropsMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(ListProps));
Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}", string.Join(", ", listProps(this)));
```

changes:

- need to pass in a target for `ldarg.0`
- need to specify a target type with `box`
- need to split `ldarg.0` and `call` / `callvirt`
- always prefer `callvirt` on instance methods unless you *really* know why

Comment: Aha! Interesting. Indeed it works! Thanks.